# Assigning list to another list

Tags: c#

I have following code that I dont understand why my list on main method able to change or effected by another list?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> t = new List<string>();
            t.Add("a");
            t.Add("b");
            t.Add("c");


            B b = new B(t);
            b.Add();
            Console.WriteLine(t.Count.ToString()); //why Output 4


        }
    }

    class B
    {
        public List<string> mylist2 { get; set; }
        public B(List<string> lsarg)
        {
            mylist2 = new List<string>(); //new allocate new location?
            mylist2 = lsarg;
        }
        public void Add()
        {
            mylist2.Add("hi");
        }
    }
```

In B class's constructor I already allocate new location to a new field as mylist2.

Comment: You assign a new list to mylist2 then immediately after, overwrite it with lsarg!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is in the line

```
mylist2 = lsarg;
```

At this point, mylist2 and lsarg are the same list, and modifications to one will be seen by the other.  If your intention was for mylist2 to have all the values of lsarg, but not be a copy of it, then you can do something like

```
mylist2 = new List<string>(lsarg); //new collection allocate, but copy old collection objects
```

If you want to prove to yourself that the lists are the same, note that your code will work identically without the line

```
mylist2 = new List<string>();
```

Comment: so mylist2 does grow up? on memory?

Comment: mylist2, in your original code, winds up just being an alias for lsargs, and not taking up much additional memory.  If you instead make a new list and keep it, then it will take more memory, but will be GC'd when it goes out of scope, so it won't be a long-lived resource hit.

Answer (score 1):

After creating new instance for mylist2, you are again assigning same reference of lsarg to it.

```
 public B(List<string> lsarg)
        {
            mylist2 = new List<string>(); //new allocate new location?
            mylist2 = lsarg; // assigns the same reference as lsarg
        }
```

Instead you must add a copy of each item. Something like following

```
public B(List<string> lsarg)
        {
            mylist2 = new List<string>(); 
            lsarg.ForEach(l=> mylist2.Add(l));
        }
```

Comment: so if I add new value for list like (t.Add("s")) does mylist2 in B object will grow up? I mean in memory B object will be grow?

Comment: No, it will only add to t.